# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError while loading libRETS jar

Tags: java, swig

I am trying to load a jar for a library originally written in C++ but has native bindings for java as well. I did that through swig, and it created the following files for me - [image]

The file of interest for me was librets.jar(in the third column below the librets directory). I imported it in a test project in java, and following the documentation, I wrote the following piece of code:

```
package test;
import librets.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws RetsHttpException, RetsReplyException, RetsException {
        System.out.println("Hello world!");
        RetsSession session = new RetsSession("http://demo.crt.relators.org:6103/rets/login");
    }
}
```

Now when I run this, I get the following runtime Exception, and I don't have any clue:

```
Hello world!
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: librets.libretsJNI.swig_module_init()V
    at librets.libretsJNI.swig_module_init(Native Method)
    at librets.libretsJNI.<clinit>(libretsJNI.java:787)
    at librets.RetsSession.<clinit>(RetsSession.java:225)
    at test.Test.main(Test.java:7)
```

Any help what could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

https://www.chilkatsoft.com/java-loadLibrary-MacOSX.asp link helped me find the solution. All I had to do was include the `.jnilib` file through `System.load` in my code.

```
package test;
import librets.*;

public class Test {

    static {
        try {
            System.load("/Users/Rai/Softwares/libRETS/build/swig/java/liblibrets.jnilib");
        } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
          System.err.println("Native code library failed to load.\n" + e);
          System.exit(1);
        }
      }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws RetsHttpException, RetsReplyException, RetsException {
        System.out.println("Hello world!");
        RetsSession session = new RetsSession("http://demo.crt.relators.org:6103/rets/login");
    }
}
```